MAUI Shell TitleView not working properly in iOS
I have added a TitleView for my Shell which displays the title of the page based on my data and a image.
Code for reference:
The above code is working perfectly in Android but not in iOS.
The problem with iOS is the Label control is not fitting properly in the Grid and it is overlapping on the Grid.Column="1". Please check the below screenshots from Android and iOS for better understanding:
Screenshot from Android:
Screenshot from iOS:
Is it a known issue of Shell.TitleView in iOS device or am I missing something?

Please don't show code as images, always use text.

Which .NET version do you use? Cannot reproduce in .NET8.

I have fixed it by setting MaximumWidthRequest property value in iOS, that helped. thanks

You should set a fixed width for your Label. * Definition means you want it to take as much space as there is (i.e Fill).
